# Page looking diff. after refresh

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I'm having a strange problem where some Icons in my header tile expanded when the page initial load. But when refresh the page, the header tile icons is at where they are supposed to be:

[image]

[image]

Here is the code for the header.jsp file that I include in all pages:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@page import="Entity.User" %>
<% User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user"); %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fakebook</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/fakebookStyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<% if(user!=null){ %>controller?funktion=newsfeed<% }else{ %>/index.html<% } %>">Fakebook</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" class="iconStyle glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </div>
            <form role="search" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
        <% if(user != null){ %>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right" style="margin-top: 15px;">
            <a href="controller?funktion=profile"><b><%= user.getFornamn() %> <%= user.getEfternamn() %></b></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="controller?funktion=logout" class="btn btn-default"><b>Logout</b></a>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        <% } else { %>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any media queries running in your stylesheet? Also, do you have a live version of this site?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with the glyphicons